# In these examples one has bare infinitive and the other has to-infinitive what is the difference?

Tags: difference

> In an examination it is more important to answer accurately than to finish quickly.
>
> I am socially and politically conscious and wish to do more than serve myself

Comment: How is the use of to-infinitive or bare infinitive decided?

Comment: Can you state which verbs in your examples you are asking about.

Answer (score 1):

THERE IS NO GENERAL RULE.

It is a property of the particular words that govern the clause.

*Important* takes a to-infinitive clause (or a *that* clause).

*Do more than* takes a bare infinitive clause.

There is no principle or logic behind this: it is (or should be) part of the dictionary entry for the word, and just has to be learnt.